# Google Chrome Cache

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

I have an html page that embeds a flash (flex) application.

I have the following headers:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-STORE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

In addition, each time I release a new version of the app, I change the file name. So, it becomes something like MyApp_v1.swf, which is then updated to MyApp_v2.swf.

Despite this, chrome still caches the html page and the swf file. This is a major problem, as clients do not then see the updated swf unless they clear their browser cache.

I even tried to get around this with changing the htaccess file, and renaming the index.html file that hosts the swf file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/app[R,L] 
DirectoryIndex index.html #this was changed from myapp.html
```

Even after doing this, Chrome still caches the swf, and is STILL reading from the old html file. I do a view source on the html, and its still showing the old file.

This all works fine in any other browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two bug reports relate, some good relevant information in here:

[Issue 28035 - chromium - Cache doesn't adhear to No cache options ( google crome )](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=28035)

[Issue 64139 - chromium - Cache isn't revalidated properly, no-cache directive](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64139)

Another solution may be to add specific `cache-control` or `pragma` HTTP headers as mentioned in the links above

Also, dumb question, did you clear chrome cache before testing your `<meta>` no-cache tags? wondering if it is still using cache from before your changes.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a complete solution, since its not possible for me to tell all my clients to clear their cache. Basically, they are stuck forever in no-mans land with the incorrect page forever! I guess one other option is to move the entire application into a new directory on the server, and use an .htaccess redirect. This should force a proper refresh and override the browser cache, right?

Comment: if you add a request parameter in the link of any src or href attribute like src="mipaht.jpg?ver=1" will force the browser to update the source, works for javascript, images, css, so maybe in this case will work also...

Comment: and if you use a dynamic string, like the datetime, you can make sure that users always download a new version and never cache. example: `src="myfile.swf?ver=1407279708`

Answer (score 2):

Use this "no-store" extra tag, and the cache works fine in Chromium (Chrome) as in the other capable browsers:

header("Cache-Control: no-cache, **no-store**, must-revalidate");

header("Pragma: no-cache, **no-store**");

Answer (score 2):

For all you guys struggeling with this
i found something simple that works...

**i tried**
 1. ctrl + f5
 2. ctrl + shift + 5
 3. setting the "no cache" in developer tools..

What worked for me in the end is to
**Just hold the CTRL key while you click the reload icon!**

Comment: That's not a solution. If the page states "no-cache" you shouldn't have to force it manually to respect the directive. Also, this would work with or without the no-cache specified.

Comment: Maybe not the solution but sure was handy.