# How to disable caching 100%

Tags: php, html, caching

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cache Control fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599382/cache-control-fails)

I am currently using:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
```

and

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Yet it still caches

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: You want to disable cache for all user forever? or just for development?

Comment: But the browsers do send "If-Modified-Since" requests, or?

Comment: @Bondye I am using Google Chrome and I want to disable it for one of my sites.

Comment: There is our friend Chrome again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918408/google-chrome-cache

Comment: UWhy you rewrite your `Cache-Control` header? I think you just need to send the header like this: `header('Cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate');`.

Comment: Dear Stack overflow. Could you provide original question link when you mark something as Duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

You can also add [Pragma: no-cache](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.32). And make sure `Last-Modified` is far enough in the past: some small clock skews between the client and the server could trick your client into thinking it has a fresh version of the document; use `Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT` for example. And also add an [Expires](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.21) header with date in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I normally add this in my .htaccess

```
<filesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
FileETag None
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

Modify the fileMatch to add other extentions ...

Answer (score 0):

Add timestamp to the end of each URI, and the browser won't retrieve it from cache (as it will be with another URI on the next load)

Comment: That is a ugly solution if you're not using ajax.